# Access the element of an unordered_set with a hash

Tags: c++, unordered-set

```
template<class T>
struct handle{
   ...
   std::size_t index;
   ...
};

template<class T>
struct foo{
  ...
  struct eq {
    bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<handle<T>> &a,
                    const std::shared_ptr<handle<T>> &b) const
    {
      return a->index == b->index;
    }
  };

  struct hash {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::shared_ptr<handle<T>> &a) const
    {
      return a->index;
    }
  };
  std::unordered_set <std::shared_ptr<handle<T>>, hash, eq> handle_set;

...
};
```

The handle_set is a view into some `std::vector<T>`. I basically want to check if someone has a reference to an element in that vector like this

```
std::size_t index_from_vector = 5;
if(handle_set.count(index_from_vector)){
  //handle exisits 
}
```

But this doesn't work because an `unordered_set` needs the key type, so I would have to do it like this

```
auto sp = std::make_shared<handle<T>>(..,index_from_vector,..);

if(handle_set.count(sp)){
  //handle exisits 
}
```

That means I always would have to create a dummy `shared_ptr` if I want to check if there is a handle to a specific element in a vector.

Is there a way to access an `unordered_set` with only the hash?

I currently use a `unordered_map` for this

```
std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::shared_ptr<handle<T>>> handle_map;
```

But updating `handle_map` is a bit of a pain because I would need to update `handle.index` and the key. This gets a bit awkward and an `unordered_set` would greatly simplify this.

Maybe there is even another data structure that would fit better?

Comment: Great question. I am trying to find solution for similar problem and in my case there is no workaround - I need to access the container just with the hash. Unfortunately, the more I search the more I am afraid it is not possible with the STL implementation.